# HttpRequestServlet - getting body (getInputStream) in Exception Handler - java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Tags: java, spring, exception, servlets

I have some problem with getting body of HttpRequestServlet.
Using this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
public void myExceptionHandler(HttpServletRequest requset
                                     ) throws IOException {
    String theString = IOUtils.toString(requset, GetInputStream, MY_CODING); 


    }
```

It throws:  `java.io.IOException: Stream closed`.
How to deal with it ?

Comment: You can only read the request once. When handled or when an exception occurs you cannot read it again as it has already been processed. If you want it to work you would have to create a filter that wraps the request, buffers the input stream and re-read that. (See the spring RequestLogging filters for inspiration).

Comment: Did you mean it: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.html ?

Comment: That one indeed. Check the sources.